# Set highlighted record on a list page through code on called object

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

On the CustListPage I have added functionality on the ribbon which opens a popup/dialog form from where you can see related Customers.
How do I, on selection of one of the related customers on my dialog, jump to that customer on the listpage?

What I’ve tried so far:
I’ve added a method (lets call it setActiveRecord) on the CustTableListPageInteraction class that should set the activeRecord on the listpage to the record I’m passing to this method.  I’m passing the CustTableListPageInteraction class to the dialog form, using a parm method.  Now on my dialog form I can see that I receive the CustTableListPageInteraction class.  However, I’m unable to execute my method setActiveRecord on the CustTableListPageInteraction, because I get a “object not initialized”.

What is the best route to follow to update a ListPage from a called object?  Because the listpage is driven by the class, I find it very difficult to pass parameters back.